# Python: check if a variable exists in a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

i have 3 files in my folder. (pythonapp.py, numbers.txt, usednumbers.txt).
So basically my app grabs a random string from (numbers.txt) and saves it to a variable. Then it writes the variable to (usednumbers.txt). But the problem is i don't want to get any duplicate strings written to (usednumbers.txt). So i'd like my app to check whenever it grabs a new random string from (numbers.txt), that if it has been already used in the past (so if it exists in usednumbers.txt)

```
#imports-------------------------------
import random

#variables-----------------------------
line = random.choice(open('numbers.txt').readlines()) #get a random string
textfile = open("usednumbers.txt", "a") #open usednumbers txt file

#main----------------------------------
#here: need to check if our selected random variable "line"
#is in txt file "usednumbers.txt", if it exists there, we get a new random number
#if it doesn't exist there, we continue and write the variable there (below)

textfile.write(line) #store the number we are going to use
textfile.close() #so in future we avoid using this number again
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code little checking again and again into the file will be overkill and reading is time expensive.

So you can read number file and filter the number which are not present in usednumber and choose a random number from it.

```
#imports-------------------------------
import random

#variables-----------------------------
numbers = open('numbers.txt').read().splitlines() #get a random string

# alreday in usednumbes 
already_in_file = set([x for x in open("usednumbers.txt", "r").read().splitlines()])

# filtering only those number swhich are not in number.txt
numbers = [x for x in numbers if x not in already_in_file]

#choose random number
if len(numbers) >0 :  
  line = random.choice(numbers)

  #main----------------------------------
  textfile = open("usednumbers.txt", "a") #open usednumbers txt file
  textfile.writelines(str(line)+"\n") #store the number we are going to use
  textfile.close() #so in future we avoid using this number again
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the chosen line is in the lines of the text file.

```
#imports-------------------------------
import random

#variables-----------------------------
line = random.choice(open('numbers.txt').readlines()) #get a random string
textfile = open("usednumbers.txt", "a") #open usednumbers txt file

#main----------------------------------
#here: need to check if our selected random variable "line"
#is in txt file "usednumbers.txt", if it exists there, we get a new random number
#if it doesn't exist there, we continue and write the variable there (below)
while(line in open('usednumbers.txt').readlines()):
    line = random.choice(open('numbers.txt').readlines()) #get a random string

textfile.write(line) #store the number we are going to use
textfile.close() #so in future we avoid using this number again
```

Update:

Not the most time performant solution.

See the solution provided by @Suryaveer Singh for a more optimized solution.

Comment: Solution working but suppose we have a few thousands number in `number.txt` then while loop will run forever since the read-write operation is expensive. The complexity of the solution is more than O(n^2) so if you have 1million number in the file then it will take years to check.

Comment: @SuryaveerSingh Also, not only the read-write operations are expensive but also, the solution is based on pure randomness. So, if both files have million of entries and there are only a few entries in numbers.txt mising in usednumbers.txt, it might take literally forever for one of these entries to be selected randomly in the middle of million others.

Comment: exactly, I was trying to convey this only. Thanks for understanding :)
I have posted my answer you can check that

Comment: @SuryaveerSingh I did, I upvoted it. Thanks for pointing it out. :)